# SQL - Select values from one field that does not contain 0 value in an other field

Tags: mysql

Do you know how can i get values from Field 1 that does not contain 0 value in Field 2.
For example I would like to select only "BBB" and "DDD" from the table below :

| Field 1 | Field 2 |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 |
| AAA | 2 |
| AAA | 0 |
| BBB | 1 |
| BBB | 2 |
| CCC | 0 |
| CCC | 2 |
| DDD | 3 |

(BBB and DDD don't contain 0 values in Field2)

Comment: 'select only "BBB" and "DDD"' - literally ?,or do you mean all rows for bbb and ddd?

Comment: `select field_1 from table where field_1 not in (select field_1 from table where field_2 = 0)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways in which it could be achieved:

##### Using Subquery:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Field1
FROM your_table
WHERE Field1 NOT IN (
    SELECT Field1
    FROM your_table
    WHERE Field2 = 0
);
```

---

##### Using `group by` and `having`

```sql
SELECT Field1
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Field1
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Field2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

*[sample run](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8g8uosEWRb9gaRASPgQSua/1)*

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `group by` and `having` clauses, the condition is that the count of rows where Field2 equals 0 must be zero :

```
select Field1
from mytable
group by Field1
having count(case when Field2 = 0 then 1 end) = 0;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/I45eKsoo)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `NOT EXISTS`

```
select m.* 
from my_table m
where not exists (select 1 from my_table mt  where m.field1 = mt.field1 and field2 = 0);
```

Or with having clause

```
select field1 
from my_table
group by field1
having min(field2) <> 0;
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/2FyxCf7b)